# Adequate sftp for PHP

Tags: php, sftp

I need to implement files downloading from sftp server with PHP7.
I see, I have http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ssh2-sftp.php functions.
Among them I have `ssh2_scp_recv` and `ssh2_scp_send`.
I see that these functions accept full remote path, as scp do.
I see that I can use follow code:

```
$format = "ssh2.sftp://%d%s";
$remotePath = "/csv/$fileName";
$link = sprintf($format, intval($sftp), $remotePath);

$read = 0;
$filesize = filesize($link);

while (
    ($read < $filesize) && 
    ($buffer = fread($remote, $filesize - $read))
) {
    $read += strlen($buffer);
    if (fwrite($local, $buffer) === FALSE)
    {
        die("Failed to write to local file: $file\n");
    }
}
```

But I receive the error:

```
PHP Warning:  filesize(): stat failed for ssh2.sftp://36/csv/20180521_export_fraud_weborama_weborama_ru.ok
```

I think it related to following thing. tha tI ave no size:

```
print_r(ssh2_sftp_stat(ssh2_sftp($connection), $remotePath))

Array
(
    [7] => 0
    [size] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [uid] => 0
    [5] => 0
    [gid] => 0
    [2] => 33188
    [mode] => 33188
    [8] => 1526868072
    [atime] => 1526868072
    [9] => 1526921030
    [mtime] => 1526921030
)
```

I just can not believe, that there is no normal implementation of sftp for PHP.

In same time I success to fetch the files with shell sftp client.

**UPDATE**

```
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection)
```

Comment: Please reduce the number of exclamation marks in your text. Thanks.

Comment: Would you edit your post to show the code that defines `$sftp`. and establishes the SFTP connection?

Comment: Your phrasing differs between an "absolut path" and a "relative ftp path".  That does not make sense, there is no such thing as a "ftp path". What you call a "remote full path" is the path of the object within that server. It is irrelevant (and none of your business from the outside) what absolute path in the servers file system that might map to. There is only one path to an object on such a server, exactly the path as specified in the object's URL.

Comment: So what the suggestion? What should be working PHP code for fetch remote file?

Comment: I do not get your intro about `ssh2_scp_recv`. You mention them but you never show any code or results about using them. + Even if you manage to get file size, you should not use `while ($read < $filesize)` anyway. Better use `feof`.

Comment: Hi, your question would be clearer if you [edit] it to: stick to the facts, and leave your frustration for another venue; include the working `sftp` command line you mention, for comparison; and cut your example down to a [mcve] showing a single problem, rather than jumping back and forth between `ssh2_scp_recv`, `filesize`, `fread`, and `ssh2_sftp_stat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every think works! It just was really empty file.

```
$format = "ssh2.sftp://%d%s";
$remotePath = "/csv/$fileName";
$link = sprintf($format, intval($sftp), $remotePath);

if (!$remote = fopen($link, 'r'))
{
    die("Failed to open remote file: $fileName");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> ssh2.sftp://36/csv/20180521_export_fraud_weborama_weborama_ru.ok

This is [not a valid URL](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ssh2.php): it implies that the data is on a host named "36" which is not allowed as a DNS name - but you appear to have done this quite deliberately - `intval($sftp)`. See link for how to construct the URL.

Maybe you've been trying to be helpful and trim out code you think is redundant from your example but there appears to be a lot of other things wrong with your code.

> $filesize = filesize($link);

Not all file operations are implemented across all file wrappers - although ssh_sftp2 is an exception (see previous link). But why poll the size? Just read to EOF. Not that your read operations will work - the code above never opens a file handle.

Comment: See https://secure.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ssh2.php - *In addition to accepting traditional URI login details, the ssh2 wrappers will also reuse open connections by **passing the connection resource in the host portion of the URL**.*

Comment: I just wanted to point out that the URL is *potentially* valid.

Comment: > This is not a valid URL: it implies that the data is on a host named "36" which is not allowed < This isn't URL, this is URI for access the resources. And it works.

Comment: Not in the code you have shown us ($sftp is not initialized in the code). Please read my response before commenting/downvoting.